# Hi. I am new to R and am really struggling with writing my function with for and while loop. Can someone tell me the for and while loop for the qs?

Tags: r, function

Write a function `h1` which uses a for-loop and the explicit formulation

> h(x, n) = 1 + x + x2 + ...xn = ∑xn

Code:

```
h2 <- function(x,n){
  i <- 1
  out=0
  for (i  in seq(from=0,to=n)) {
    out = out + x^i
    }
}
```

I have tried this but this doesnt seem to work? Is there an alternative way to find the for and while loop for this problem

Answer (score 2):

A function returns the result of the last statement in its body which in this case is `for` but `for` always returns NULL.  (The line after the `for` is regarded as part of the `for` so it is not regarded as the last line.)

```
res <- for(i in 1:3) i
res
## NULL
```

Make sure that `out` is the last statement run.  That is add this

```
out
```

as the last line in the body just before the final `}`.

Note that this one-linear would also work:

```
sum(x^(0:n))
```